# Is there an alternative to Gravatar?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Is there an alternative for displaying an avatar other than Gravatar-

I don't really want to sign up to the Gravatar hosting service, would it be possible to add an option so users could just use an existing image URL?

I have an avatar hosted on another service, it would be more convenient to just cut and paste it, IMO users might be more inclined to have an avatar if they didn't have to sign up to another image hosting service - what's everyones opinion on this?

cheers.

Comment: @annalear, sorry i missed the tag change!

Comment: I'm glad this was *finally* done. I remember I resisted putting up my picture due to the pain in the butt to have to create yet another account someplace else just to have a image here. It felt like pointless busywork. Just letting you upload a picture is the obvious way it should have been all along. But you got there now, so we'll forget about the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is no longer any requirement for gravatar!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/)